# sort a vector not working

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector, stl

I have the overloaded operator in `Animal` like this

```
// A must be comparable to be used as keys
bool operator<(const Archivo &right) const
{
    return nombreArchivo < right.nombreArchivo;
}
```

and in my `main` I call

```
std::vector<Animal*> animalesConConcha;
// add some objects
std::sort(animalesConConcha.begin(), animalesConConcha.end());

std::cout<<"\n\n\nOrdered:\n";

for(it=animalesConConcha.begin(); it!=animalesConConcha.end(); it++)
{
    cout<<(*it)->nombre<<" | "<<(*it)->indice<<endl;
}
```

But the output is still unsorted.

Comment: Make sure you add a language tag when asking questions in a specific language (I've added C++ for you).

Comment: Those are `Animal*`s, not `Animal` objects. `std::sort()` is therefore sorting them by their addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing pointers in your vector, not objects. `std::sort` does not dereference the pointers but compares the actual pointer values. (Technically, this does not have a guaranteed behaviour, because `<` is used directly on the pointers.)

Solution 1: Store the objects directly in the vector:

```
vector<Animal> animalesConConcha;
sort(animalesConConcha.begin(), animalesConConcha.end());

for(it=animalesConConcha.begin(); it!=animalesConConcha.end(); it++)
{
    cout<< it->nombre<<" | "<< it->indice<<endl;
}
```

Solution 2: Specify a custom comparison functor for `std::sort`:

```
struct Comparison
{
    bool const operator()(Animal *lhs, Animal *rhs) const
   {
         return (*lhs) < (*rhs);
    }
};

sort(animalesConConcha.begin(), animalesConConcha.end(), Comparison());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are storing a vector of pointers to `Animal` you are not giving chance for the `operator<()` of your class to work. The `sort` function uses the `operator<()` for the type of what is in the vector - in this case a pointer to `Animal`, not an instance of `Animal`.

Therefore the array is sorted based on `operator<()` for **pointers** which as 0x499602D2 says will result in the array of pointers being sorted in ascending address.

If you want it to work this way, either define a custom comparator or use `vector<Animal>` instead of `vector<Animal*>`

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that you don't have a vector with Animals.

In your code, there is a vector of pointers to Animals.

Change

```
vector<Animal*>
```

for

```
vector<Animal>
```

And tell us if is working now.

Comment: Hum... Try again ? :)

Comment: You need to add 4 spaces before `vector` instead of using `>  ` in order for it to be formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's polymorphism you want to achieve which is the reason why you're using `Animal*`s instead of stack-allocated `Animal` objects. Since you are using pointers as the value type of the vector, `std::sort()`s use of `operator<()` resolves to the built-in overload which will simply compare the addresses of the pointers instead of your custom operator.

Conveniently, `std::sort()` takes a predicate as an optional third parameter. You can pass a callable entity to be invoked as the comparator:

```
std::sort(animalesConConcha.begin(), animalesConConcha.end(),
[] (Animal* lhs, Animal* rhs) {
    return lhs->nombreArchivo < rhs->nombreArchivo;
});
```

If lambda expressions are not supported by your compiler, you can use a function or a class instance with an overloaded `operator()` instead.